# Possible to increase resolution of points in Matlab export_fig?

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have a background image and some additional points plotted on it. I provided an example below, and the background image is just a plain white image just for simplicity's sake:

```
testim=ones(1024,1024);

imshow(testim); hold on

for j=1:20
    plot(20+.33,20.27+j*10, '.r','MarkerSize',4);
end
for j=1:20
    plot(300+.33,20.27+j*10, '.r','MarkerSize',4);
end
for j=1:15
    plot(j*20+.33,220.27, '.r','MarkerSize',4);
end
for j=1:15
    plot(j*20+.33,20.27, '.r','MarkerSize',4);
end
```

When I zoom in on the Matlab figure, it looks like:

[image]

I then zoom-out back to the original figure size and then save it with `export_fig`:

```
export_fig exportFig-q100-painters-testim.png -q100 -painters
export_fig exportFig-q102-painters-testim.png -q102 -painters
```

When I open those png files and zoom-in, the image looks like:

[image]

That is not what I wanted as I was hoping each dot in the original plot would become one-pixel in size in the zoomed-in png file, but instead for each center pixel, there are about 6 red-fainted pixels due to blurring. Is there any way to get rid of this blur in export_fig?

EDIT:

When I use `print(gcf,'foo.png','-dpng','-r300')` to save the figure as an image, the points are still very blurry even when I adjust the dpi to have values such as 1, 100, 300, 900, etc

EDIT2:

It's easier to see how `export_fig out.png -q100 -painters -a1` doesn't help when trying the plotting below:

```
testim=rand(1024,1024);

imshow(testim); hold on

for j=1:100
    plot(20+.33,20.27+j*2, '.r','MarkerSize',4);
end
for j=1:100
    plot(300+.33,20.27+j*2, '.r','MarkerSize',4);
end
for j=1:60
    plot(j*5+.33,220.27, '.r','MarkerSize',4);
end
for j=1:60
    plot(j*5+.33,20.27, '.r','MarkerSize',4);
end
```

EDIT3

When I use `saveas` to save as a pdf when the background image is 1024x1024 with the following code:

```
testim=rand(1024,1024);
f2=figure(2); imshow(testim); hold on
plot(217.47, 227.3, '.r','MarkerSize',1);
plot(218.74, 226.8, '.r','MarkerSize',1);
plot(219.2, 227.1, '.r','MarkerSize',1);
plot(219.1, 228.5, '.r','MarkerSize',1);
saveas(f2, 'saveas-pdf-testim-1024-marker1.pdf');
```

the result is:

[image]

But it looks bad when the background image is 4096x4096:

```
testim=rand(4096,4096);
f2=figure(2); imshow(testim); hold on
plot(217.47, 227.3, '.r','MarkerSize',1);
plot(218.74, 226.8, '.r','MarkerSize',1);
plot(219.2, 227.1, '.r','MarkerSize',1);
plot(219.1, 228.5, '.r','MarkerSize',1);
saveas(f2, 'saveas-pdf-testim-4096-marker1.pdf');
```

[image]

Comment: no, that did not lead to any improvement

Comment: Note that the `-q100` option is only useful with JPEG, PDF and EPS outputs (PDF and EPS will use JPEG encoding for bitmap data). PNG files don't use this option.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing in your output is anti-aliasing. It causes lines to look prettier in a bitmap.

There are two levels of anti-aliasing being applied:

1. MATLAB itself nowadays renders with anti-aliasing. You can turn this off using

   ```
   set(gcf,'GraphicsSmoothing','off')
   ```
2. `export_fig` has an option to control anti-aliasing for bitmapped file formats:

   > ```
   > -a1, -a2, -a3, -a4 - option indicating the amount of anti-aliasing to
   >                  use for bitmap outputs. '-a1' means no anti-aliasing;
   >                  '-a4' is the maximum amount (default).
   > ```

   The default is `-a4`, which is the maximum amount of anti-aliasing. It causes the figure to be rendered at 4x the resolution, and then scales the resulting image. Adding `-a1` to the `export_fig` command disables the anti-aliasing.

   ```
   export_fig out.png -a1
   ```

The combination of both makes your figure much more crisp. However, the rendering of dotted lines still looks very poor IMO. Try adding `-m4` or some such value to increase the resolution of the exported bitmap by an integer factor compared to the screen rendering.

Comment: when I tried that and saved as jpeg, I don't see much improvement

Comment: I didn't see much improvement when saving as PNG either

Comment: I provided example code in EDIT2 to see how `export_fig` with `-a1` doesn't show improvement

Comment: I didn't know about this option. Is this available in all or recent versions?  (+1)

Comment: @SecretAgentMan: It’s been in `export_fig` for many, many years, maybe since the first version. It shouldn’t be used any more since anti-aliasing is part of HG2. The default value is wrong now IMO. https://github.com/altmany/export_fig/issues/292

Comment: that's not really helping either. The closest that seems to be working is in EDIT3

Comment: @user5739619: I was answering the question “Is there any way to get rid of this blur in export_fig?”. The 3rd edit exports as vector drawing, not bitmap. It also shows dot markers, not a dotted line, which is way different. MATLAB’s dotted lines have always sucked. It seems you are looking for something different than what you asked about. If what you want is to have small, round dots on top of large pixels of an image, then you need to ask how to do that.

Comment: yes, I'm interested in dots/points, which is why the title of my question says "points". I'm not interested in connecting the points/dots with lines. Sorry for the confusion